# Explicit solutions to a one parameter family of solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The first given equation is
$$8x^2-y^2=C$$
and differentiating this verifies that it is equal to $\frac{ydy}{dx}=8x$ which is our differential equation
$$16x-2yy'=0$$
$$yy'=8x$$

I'm having trouble finding explicit solutions in each of the four quadrants, how do I continue to find the solutions and their respective intervals?

Comment: @almagest I'm trying to find all explicit solutions y=$\phi(x)$ of the differential equation

Comment: @almagest yes I did plot $8x^2-y^2=8$ and it is a hyperbola with symmetry around the y-axis but when I used your answer of $\sqrt{8x^2-c}$ the computer said it was incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating the differential equation recovers your original form.

The family of curves (as $C$) varies give a family of hyperbolae. For example $C=-1$ gives

[image]

and $C=2$ gives

[image]

Alll the curves are symmetrical about both axes, so $$y=\sqrt{8x^2-C}\text{ with }C=-1$$ gives the solution to the differential equation in the upper half-plane (ie 1st and 2nd quadrants). Note that there are no values for small $|x|$. Similarly, $$y=-\sqrt{8x^2-C}$$ gives the solution in the lower half-plane.

Similarly for the second graph with $C=2$. This time both solutions ($+\sqrt{}$ and $-\sqrt{}$) work for all $x$, but there is a gap in the $y$ values.

---

Added later.

As usual with solution curves for ODE the curves for the family of solutions fill the plane. The plot below with curves for a range of values of $C$ from -20 to +50 may make that a little clearer.

[image]

Note the degenerate conic, which is a pair of intersecting lines, that are also the asymptotes for the other solutions.

Comment: I tried both options of the answer you gave and it said both were incorrect. However the domain of the first and fourth quadrant are both (1,$\infty$)

Comment: @EricBrown Yes. It is correct to say that if $C=8$, then there is no solution for $|x|<1$. But the objective in math is to communicate clearly and correctly. To say that $y=\sqrt{8x^2-8}$ gives the part of the solution to the ODE which lies in the upper half plane is both clear and correct. Any half-competent mathematician can see that there will be no (real) values for $|x|<1$. Actually very few competent mathematicians would try to give separate equations for the upper and lower half-planes. The equation $y^2=8x^2-8$ is a more helpful description.

Comment: But by far the best description for the solution is $$x^2-\frac{y^2}{8}=1$$ because that is the standard form for a conic and immediately shows that it is a hyperbola. So I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve by recounting your experiences with plotting software.

Comment: sorry for the frustration but why did you choose $C$ to equal $-1$ and $2$

Comment: Mainly random, but I wanted one positive and one negative value to show that the solution curves fill the plane.

Comment: I finally figured out what was making my answer incorrect, I forgot to add in the equation $8x^2-y^2=8$ which concludes to your original answer of $\sqrt{8x^2-c}$ but now $c=8$ and after factoring and removal of $\sqrt{8}$ comes out to be $y=\pm \sqrt{8}\sqrt{(x+1)(x-1)}$ which is how the website wanted the answer structured. Sorry for the lack of awareness on my part and thank you for your unwavering assistance through this whole ordeal.

Comment: It is always a fine balance in MSE how much to give in a question. Few people bother to answer long questions, but many people get irritated by short ones. Most of the people providing good answers are academics and they get irritated when lazy students just want their weekly assignments answered for them. MSE has not yet got the right way of dealing with that whole issue. It is fairly intractable. Good luck in your math studies. You are demonstrating one indispensable quality for success - persistence and hard work!

Answer (score 0):

from $yy'=8x$ we have
$$
ydy=8xdx
$$
we can write the solution $y^2=8x^2+C$, that is an implicit function, or in the form
$$
y=\pm \sqrt{8x^2+C}
$$
that is a couple of explicit functions.

Comment: I see where you're going with this but could you give me the general form that an explicit solution should be in.

Comment: I added something. Is it the answer you need?

Comment: Yes I believe so. Now if I want those explicit functions to apply to all four quadrants do I have to change the signs both in front and inside the function?

Comment: @EricBrown Those equations **give** the explicit form for all four quadrants! Try sketching them!

Comment: Oh yeah duh! sorry for my slowness, this is my first explicit solution problem

Comment: @almagest Shouldn't the equation be $y^2=8x^2-C$?

Comment: @EricBrown It makes no difference $C$ is arbitrary - it can take positive or negative values. I agree that he has chosen to use $-C$ where you used $C$ in the question, but it makes no difference. Maybe my answer helps?